# PivotTable.js OLAP not considering field having more than one value

Tags: javascript, pivot-table, olap, olap-cube, pivottable.js

I am trying to use the [PivotTable.JS Script by Nicolas Kruchten](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable) and am facing the following problem:

Some of the fields in my data have more than one value. For E.g. in the following entry, there are more than one 'segment' and 'trend':

```
{'Segment': ('Lending','Marketplace'), 'Trend': ('Investments', 'Expansion'),  'Month_year': 'Oct 2016', 'Link': 'http://www.geektime.com/2016/10/02/german-credit-startup-smava-bags-34-million-series-c-investment/', 'Title': 'Smava has raised $34 million Series C investment from Runa Capital', 'Country': 'Germany'},
```

Now,

1. If I pass the Segment as a Tuple `( )`, the PivotTable UI just considers the last entry (Marketplace), and ignores all before it (Lending). So it counts 1 for Marketplace and 0 for Lending.
2. If I pass the segment as a List / Array `[ ]`, the PivotTable UI considers "Lending, Marketplace" as a separate entity all together, instead of counting it separately in both "Lending", as well as "Marketplace".
3. If I pass the segment as a dictionary `{ }`, the script doesn't work at all.

I cannot break and repeat the entry, with one have "Lending" and another "Marketplace" - as it will lead to a lot of duplicate counts of other fields. E.g. breaking and repeating this entry for both 'segment' and 'trend' will result in four counts for the 'country: Germany', while actually there is only one.

I am stuck at this problem, and need a solution to address it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: You need to 'normalize' your data as 'facts': dataset that have exactly one value per column. In your case, you can expand sample row into several rows (for each unique value from 'Segment' and 'Trend' arrays) before passing the data to the component that calculates a pivot table.

Comment: That's the whole problem. If I split and expand the row/entry mentioned above, I will have 4 rows.... 

Now, in the pivot, if I have Month_year on one axis, and Country on another, my count will be 4, while it should actually be 1.

Comment: You may expand only when 'multi-value' column is selected as dimension. Pivottable.js has "onRefresh" handler and you can re-bind data after user selection (unfortunately double-rendering is unavoidable without changes in pivot.js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this library does not support multiple values per attribute, so there is no way to do what you're looking for if you are unable to break/repeat the values.

Comment: Thanks. Breaking/ repeating will duplicate the count of other cells. I checked the data in Tableau, and found the same problem. Is there a solution to deal with it at a general Pivot Table- level?

Comment: This is a pretty tough problem to solve in the general case unfortunately... I don't know of any good solutions.

Comment: Could you accept the answer please, even though it is a negative result? I'm pretty sure it's authoritative ;)

Comment: lol.. yes... what comes from your end, can't be contradicted in this case :) 

BTW, the issue is at a macro-level, across OLAPs. I have been facing the same issue in POWER BI and Tableau as well. The only solution I could think of is.... to first get all the data into browser, and then perform SQL queries using '%like%' to filter that data.... However for a pivot table with 10 rows and 10 columns, it will result in 100 queries...... that too for only one user a time :(

Thanks again for your help, and the awesome script